# Submitting form, reload content of modal after a while

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap modal to show form in Rails. User submits it, in a modal window we have progress bar, and after loading I want 'show' template to be visible in a modal.
My new.js.erb:

```
 $('#dialog h3').html("<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></i> Modal");

 $('.modal-body').html('<%= j render("form") %>');

 $('#dialog').modal("show");
```

My create.js.erb:

```
 $('.modal-body').html('<%= j render(@user) %>');
```

It works, but I want to show progress bar animation first, and later render @user partial, without closing the modal window. How to reload content without a need to click on anything? Just a smooth transition, first render one partial, and next - the other one? My progress bar script is placed in one partial and it works when I render it in my model the same way I did with @user. Maybe I should set a timer or something like that?

```
     <div class="progress">
        <div aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuenow="100" class="progress-bar progress-bar-primary" role="progressbar">
            100%
          <span class="sr-only">100% Complete (normal)</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
var bar = $('.progress-bar');
  $(function(){
    $(bar).each(function(){
      bar_width = $(this).attr('aria-valuenow');
      $(this).width(bar_width + '%');
    });
  });
 </script>
```

Comment: Can you post the loading code too?

Comment: I edited my first post :)